# Flutter: Make ListView bounce at the bottom and clamp at the top position

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

There are two types of `ScrollPhysics` that I want to apply to my `ListView`. When user reaches the bottom of the List, I want `BouncingScrollPhysics()` to take place, but when user reaches the top, it shouldn't bounce but rather perform `ClampingScrollPhysics()`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

```
// create 2 instance variables
var _controller = ScrollController();
ScrollPhysics _physics = ClampingScrollPhysics();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller.addListener(() {
    if (_controller.position.pixels <= 56)
      setState(() => _physics = ClampingScrollPhysics());
    else
      setState(() => _physics = BouncingScrollPhysics());
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
      controller: _controller,
      physics: _physics,
      itemCount: 20,
      itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text("Item $i")),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I just updated the code, earlier I was using `var` for `_physics` (and now updated it to `ScrollPhysics`) and it was causing error when assigning value to other physics, please check.

Comment: I've just relooked at your answer and I have something to add. Before setting the state billion times you should check if the var physics is already assigned to the right one. Otherwise app may lag like crazy

Comment: Yes, you're right, you can use `if-else` condition to make sure you only change it when you need. For simplicity, i didn't add them.

Comment: For me the list does not scroll anymore. (I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_scrollbar)

Answer (score 2):

I don't wont to reload every time it change the scroll position.
And I hit upon a good one. so I leave it for future readers!

```
    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.position.pixels < 0) _controller.jumpTo(0);
    });
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: oh get off it @JeremyCaney, what are you, a bot? This was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom `ScrollPhysics` class :

I found one that works great, in the great [modal_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) package, source:  https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet/pull/77

```dart
ListView(
  physics: const BottomModalScrollPhysics(),
  children: [...],
)
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class BottomModalScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  /// Creates scroll physics that prevent the scroll offset from exceeding the
  /// top bound of the modal.
  const BottomModalScrollPhysics({ScrollPhysics? parent})
      : super(parent: parent);

  @override
  BottomModalScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return BottomModalScrollPhysics(parent: buildParent(ancestor));
  }

  @override
  double applyBoundaryConditions(ScrollMetrics position, double value) {
    assert(() {
      if (value == position.pixels) {
        throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
          ErrorSummary(
              '$runtimeType.applyBoundaryConditions() was called redundantly.'),
          ErrorDescription(
              'The proposed new position, $value, is exactly equal to the current position of the '
              'given ${position.runtimeType}, ${position.pixels}.\n'
              'The applyBoundaryConditions method should only be called when the value is '
              'going to actually change the pixels, otherwise it is redundant.'),
          DiagnosticsProperty<ScrollPhysics>(
              'The physics object in question was', this,
              style: DiagnosticsTreeStyle.errorProperty),
          DiagnosticsProperty<ScrollMetrics>(
              'The position object in question was', position,
              style: DiagnosticsTreeStyle.errorProperty)
        ]);
      }
      return true;
    }());
    final direction = position.axisDirection;
    // Normal vertical scroll
    if (direction == AxisDirection.down) {
      if (value < position.pixels &&
          position.pixels <= position.minScrollExtent) {
        // underscroll
        return value - position.pixels;
      }

      if (value < position.minScrollExtent &&
          position.minScrollExtent < position.pixels) {
        // hit top edge
        return value - position.minScrollExtent;
      }
    }
    // Reversed vertical scroll
    else if (direction == AxisDirection.up) {
      if (position.maxScrollExtent <= position.pixels &&
          position.pixels < value) {
        // overscroll
        return value - position.pixels;
      }

      if (position.pixels < position.maxScrollExtent &&
          position.maxScrollExtent < value) {
        // hit bottom edge
        return value - position.maxScrollExtent;
      }
    }
    if (parent != null) return super.applyBoundaryConditions(position, value);
    return 0.0;
  }
}
```